# After updating my Mac doesn't recognize my bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

After an update my Mac doesn't recognize my bitcoin core.  The bitcoin avatar shows up in launchpad with a "?" in it.  How can I fix it?  I have been running a node 24/7 for a couple months without issue.